# Javafx fxml Scene Builder - How to show the content of an array in GUI

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I am just starting out with using GUI and javafx using Scene Builder. As a student I don't have too much experience in Programming, therefore any help is welcome.

So I have this game, which produces results in an array list in class Game. The array is set private so I access it through a "get" Method. The array contains, Names, IDs, State, Raceing Time.
Now I can print it the console (looping through the array with println), but I don't know how to get this being displayed into the GUI. Is there any best practice I can follow? I thought ListView would be the appropreate GUI Elemet but if anything else is standard practice I am happy to use it.

This is the Controller Class - It should show the content of the array

```
public class ControlResults {

   Game game = new Game();

    String test;
        @FXML
        private Label label;

        @FXML
        private Button button;  
        public void button(ActionEvent event){
        label.setText("The Results are: ");
        initializeListView() ;
        }

        @FXML
        private ListView results;
        public void initializeListView() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= game.getRaceResult().size(); i++) { 
            test = game.getRaceResult().get(i).toString(); 
            results.getItems().add(test);
        }   } 

}
```

This is the error that appears

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: In Java, list and array indexing is 0-based (starts st 0 and goes up to, but not including, `size()`).

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < game.getRaceResult().size(); i++)`

Comment: thank you, I changed it but the InvocationTargetException remains